# gnuplot: how to change font for set label command

Tags: fonts, label, gnuplot

In my gnuplot case, I need to draw some text labels on the canvas with various fonts. The code is following:
`set term gif
set output "runtime_distribution.gif"
set label 1 "stage" at 84.971, 3.25 center  front textcolor rgb "#000000" font "arial,19"`

but comes up the following error message:
`gdImageStringFT: Could not find/open font while printing string stage with font arial`

it seems that gif terminal doesn't support such font. But I also use it in 
`set xtics rotate by -45 font "arial,9"`

which can change the text font of xlablel as expected.

And based on the gnuplot manual, the `set label` command support font feature as well. So what the reason for this strange issue?

Comment: Which gnuplot version. In any case, try the pngcairo terminal which gives much better results

Comment: BTW: you should accept answers which solved a problem. This is how stackoverflow works...

Comment: I use gnuplot4.2, but I also tried 4.6, the result is same. The reason I use gif is, I need to read in the image into the Tk, as far as I know, png is not supported.

Comment: Oh, I will follow this rule.

Comment: Ok, for me your snippet works fine with 4.2.6 on Windows. How do you run gnuplot and the script? (Terminal, from Tk, ssh, ...)

Comment: Oh, I run on Linux terminal by gnuplot command_file.dat, in which the above commands are contained.

Comment: I don't know how the gif terminal in gnuplot 4.2 looks up its fonts. On my Debian system it works fine as well. Possibly you need to install the Arial true type fonts via th e package [ttf-mscorefonts-installer](http://packages.ubuntu.com/de/lucid/ttf-mscorefonts-installer), or you must to add some path to the environment variable `GDFONTPATH`. But that are only guesses, I cannot check this.